# Manage multiple glossaries in one bib file

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I am currently exploring the tools given by `glossaires-extra` when combined with `bib2gls`. But I get stuck on some points.

I have to work with multiple glossaries, so I declare my glossaries `notation` and `symbols`. I know that symbols can be define automatically with a proper package option, but I keep it like this for my example as a trial.
I would like to have (if possible) all the definition in a single file, that I named `test-entries.bib`. Here comes my first problem, I can not use the command `type=notation` for example, because it affects all the entries to this type. So, I tried with `entry-type-aliases`, but I did not succeeded to redirect each entry to its glossary. This is confirmed by the warning : `No entries defined in glossary 'notation' on line 33`.

The second point is that I would like to sort the `symbols` type by `category` then by `group` then by `name`, and I do not really know how to do so, and specially when its in the same file that other entries.

Here is a MWE. The `test-entries.bib`:

```
@acronym{html,
    short= {HTML}, 
    long= {hypertext markup language},
    category={inline},
}

@acronym{shtml,
    short= {SHTML}, 
    long= {server-parsed HTML},
    category={footer},
}

@notation{mesh,
    name={tesh},
    description={this is a lattice network},
    sort={m}, 
}

@symbol{f, %
    name={\ensuremath{ f }}, %
    description={a given function}, %
    unit= {$\varnothing$}, %
    category= {operator},
    group={latin}
}

@symbol{xi, %
    name={\ensuremath{ \xi }}, %
    description={a space variable}, %
    unit= {m}, %
    category= {variable},
    group={greek}
}

@symbol{fi, %
    name={\ensuremath{ f_i }}, %
    description={another function}, %
    unit= {$\varnothing$}, %
    category= {operator},
    group={latin}
}

@symbol{xii, %
    name={\ensuremath{ \xi_i }}, %
    description={a discretized space variable}, %
    unit= {m}, %
    category= {variable},
    group={greek}
}

@symbol{t, %
    name={\ensuremath{ t }}, %
    description={a time variable}, %
    unit= {s}, %
    category= {variable},
    group={latin}
}
```

then the main.tex :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

    \usepackage[nomain, abbreviations, record, automake]{glossaries-extra}

    %Newglossaries
    \newglossary[ntg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation} 
    \newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Nomenclature}

    % new keys must be defined before \GlsXtrLoadResources    
    \glsaddstoragekey{unit}{}{\glsentryunit}
    % name the group greek letter
    \glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greek}{Greek Symbols}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
        src={../test-entries}, % entries in symbols.bib
        entry-type-aliases={symbol=symbols},
        entry-type-aliases={notation=notation},
        sort-field={group},% sort @symbol entries by name field
        symbol-sort-fallback=name,% sort @symbol entries by name field
        identical-sort-action=description,% sort by description if sort value identical
        selection=all,
%       type=symbols,% put these entries in the symbols glossary
        save-locations=false,% location list not needed
    ]

\begin{document}

    \printunsrtglossary[type=\glsxtrabbrvtype]
    \printunsrtglossary[type=notation]
    \printunsrtglossary[type=symbols]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the resource options aren't cumulative. That is, if used multiple times the last option usually overrides the previous option of the same name. This means that:

```
    entry-type-aliases={symbol=symbols},
    entry-type-aliases={notation=notation},
```

is equivalent to just:

```
    entry-type-aliases={notation=notation},
```

You need to have all the aliases in one setting. For example:

```
    entry-type-aliases={symbol=symbols,notation=notation},
```

However, neither of these aliases work. The first (`symbol=symbols`) makes `@symbol` behave as though it was `@symbols`, but that bib entry type doesn't exist (whereas `@symbol` does). The second alias (`notation=notation`) makes `@notation` behave as though it was `@notation`, which is a redundant instruction, but also that bib entry type doesn't exist.

The only unknown entry type in your bib file is `@notation` so that's the only one that needs aliasing. I recommend you alias it to `@entry`:

```
  entry-type-aliases=
  {
    notation=entry,% make @notation behave like @entry
  },
```

When you have a single bib file that contains entries in multiple glossaries, there are several ways of assigning the type.

The first method is to ensure that the original entry type matches the required glossary type. This would mean having glossaries labelled `acronym` (to match `@acronym`), `symbol` (to match `@symbol`) and `notation` (to match `@notation`). This can be done with:

```
\usepackage[nomain, record, automake]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary*{acronym}{Abbreviations}
\newglossary*{notation}{Notation}
\newglossary*{symbol}{Nomenclature}
```

and use the resource option:

```
  type={same as original entry},
```

The `type` option in `\printunsrtglossary` also needs to be adjusted to match:

```
\printunsrtglossary[type=acronym]
\printunsrtglossary[type=notation]
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbol]
```

The second method is to filter the entries and have one `\GlsXtrLoadResources` per glossary type and set the `type`. For example:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={test-entries}, % entries in test-entries.bib
  type=\glsxtrabbrvtype,
  match={entrytype=acronym},% only consider @acronym for selection
%... other options
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={test-entries}, % entries in test-entries.bib
  entry-type-aliases=
  {
    notation=entry,% make @notation behave like @entry
  },
  type=notation,
  match={entrytype=entry},% only consider @entry for selection
%... other options
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={test-entries}, % entries in test-entries.bib
  type=symbols,
  match={entrytype=symbol},% only consider @symbol for selection
%... other options
]
```

The third method is to adjust the helper commands used to define the entries in the `.glstex` file that's created by bib2gls. The entries defined using `@acronym` in the `.bib` file are defined in the `.glstex` file using `\bibglsnewacronym`. This is defined to use `\newacronym`, so if you have used the `abbreviations` package option (as in your MWE) then you don't need to worry about it (as long as you don't override the default `type`).

Entries that are defined in the `.bib` file using `@symbol` are defined in the `.glstex` file using `\bibglsnewsymbol`. The definition of this command is provided in the `.glstex` file as:

```
\providecommand{\bibglsnewsymbol}[4]{%
 \longnewglossaryentry*{#1}{name={#3},sort={#1},category={symbol},#2}{#4}}
```

So you could define this command before `\GlsXtrLoadResources` so that it explicitly sets the `type` in the second argument of `\longnewglossaryentry*`. For example:

```
\newcommand{\bibglsnewsymbol}[4]{%
 \longnewglossaryentry*{#1}{name={#3},sort={#1},category={symbol},type={symbols},#2}{#4}}
```

This will put the entries defined with `@symbol` into the `symbols` glossary (unless explicitly overridden).

The entries defined using `@notation` were aliased to `@entry` so they are defined in the `.glstex` file using `\bibglsnewentry`. This command is provided in the `.glstex` file as:

```
\providecommand{\bibglsnewentry}[4]{%
 \longnewglossaryentry*{#1}{name={#3},#2}{#4}%
}
```

Again, you can define this command before `\GlsXtrLoadResources` so that the glossary type is explicitly set:

```
\newcommand{\bibglsnewentry}[4]{%
 \longnewglossaryentry*{#1}{name={#3},type={notation},#2}{#4}%
}
```

This method means that you don't need to change your glossary definitions (`\newglossary`) and you don't use the `type` option in the `\GlsXtrLoadResources` option list.

Regarding the sorting, you can have a main field that provides the sort value (`sort-field`) and you can have a fallback field where the sort values are identical (`identical-sort-action`) but you can't have a second fallback field if the first fallback field is also identical.

You've changed the sort field to `group` with:

```
sort-field={group}
```

and supplied a `group` field for some but not all of the entries in the `.bib` file. It's present for all the `@symbol` entries, which means that the sort value is never missing for any `@symbol` entries and so the option:

```
symbol-sort-fallback=name
```

is redundant, because there is never a need to fallback on another field.

The change in `sort-field` means that no entries are sorted according to the `sort` field (as the default `sort-field=sort` has been switched to `sort-field=group`). This means that the `sort` field set in your entry:

```
@notation{mesh,
    name={tesh},
    description={this is a lattice network},
    sort={m},
}
```

does nothing. (Incidentally, did you mean "mesh" rather than "tesh"?) The field used for sorting is now `group` but this field hasn't been set and there's no fallback field to use in its place. (`@notation` was aliased to `@entry` so `symbol-sort-fallback` doesn't apply.)

I recommend a different approach. You can filter out the symbols from the other entries and apply different sorting and group formations. The first resource set can just deal with the entries that use normal alphabetic sorting with the default `sort-field=sort`, where missing `sort` fields fallback on the `name` field for entries defined with `@entry` (`@notation` with the `notation=entry` alias) and the `short` field for entries defined with `@acronym`:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={test-entries}, % entries in test-entries.bib
  entry-type-aliases=
  {
    notation=entry,% make @notation behave like @entry
  },
  type={same as original entry},
  selection=all,
  match={entrytype=(acronym|entry)},% only select @acronym and @entry
  save-locations=false,% location list not needed
]
```

This filters out the entries so that it only selects the `@acronym` and `@entry` entries using:

```
  match={entrytype=(acronym|entry)},% only select @acronym and @entry
```

In this example, an alternative is to filter out `@symbol` instead using:

```
  not-match={entrytype=symbol},% don't select @symbol
```

This is simpler. The second resource set can then use:

```
  match={entrytype=symbol},% only select @symbol
```

to only select `@symbol` and filter out all the other entries.

You have a group title assigned using:

```
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greek}{Greek Symbols}
```

but you're not actually using a glossary style that shows the group title. Even if you do use a group style, the result will be strange if you don't ensure that the sorting will result in entries blocked according to group. The `group` field is normally assigned by the sort method to ensure this, but if you explicitly set the `group` field, then there's no guarantee that you won't have the groups scattered.

> I would like to sort the `symbols` type by `category` then by `group` then
>   by `name`

As I already mentioned, you can't sort by three fields but if your `group` fields are all `latin` and `greek` then a character code sort on the `name` field will automatically separate the Latin and Greek characters, so I don't think you actually need the `group` field set in the `.bib` file (especially if you're not using a group glossary style).

Let's suppose the file `test-entries.bib` is now:

```
@acronym{html,
    short= {HTML}, 
    long= {hypertext markup language},
    category={inline}
}

@acronym{shtml,
    short= {SHTML}, 
    long= {server-parsed HTML},
    category={footer}
}

@notation{mesh,
    name={mesh},
    description={this is a lattice network}
}

@symbol{f, %
    name={\ensuremath{ f }}, %
    description={a given function}, %
    unit= {$\varnothing$}, %
    category= {operator}
}

@symbol{xi, %
    name={\ensuremath{ \xi }}, %
    description={a space variable}, %
    unit= {m}, %
    category= {variable}
}

@symbol{fi, %
    name={\ensuremath{ f_i }}, %
    description={another function}, %
    unit= {$\varnothing$}, %
    category= {operator}
}

@symbol{xii, %
    name={\ensuremath{ \xi_i }}, %
    description={a discretized space variable}, %
    unit= {m}, %
    category= {variable}
}

@symbol{t, %
    name={\ensuremath{ t }}, %
    description={a time variable}, %
    unit= {s}, %
    category= {variable}
}
```

Then complete MWE (using the first method of assigning the `type`) is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage[nomain, record, automake]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary*{acronym}{Abbreviations} 
\newglossary*{notation}{Notation} 
\newglossary*{symbol}{Nomenclature}

% new keys must be defined before \GlsXtrLoadResources    
\glsaddstoragekey{unit}{}{\glsentryunit}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={test-entries}, % entries in test-entries.bib
  entry-type-aliases=
  {
    notation=entry,% make @notation behave like @entry
  },
  type={same as original entry},
  selection=all,
  not-match={entrytype=symbol},% don't select @symbol
  save-locations=false,% location list not needed
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={test-entries}, % entries in test-entries.bib
  type={same as original entry},
  sort-field=category,
  identical-sort-action=name,% sort by name if category is identical
  selection=all,
  save-locations=false,% location list not needed
  match={entrytype=symbol},% only select @symbol
  sort={letter-nocase}
]

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossary[type=acronym]
\printunsrtglossary[type=notation]
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbol]

\end{document}
```

The list of abbreviations looks like:

[image: Abbreviations HTML hypertext markup language SHTML server-parsed HTML]

The notation list looks like:

[image: Notation mesh this is a lattice network]

The symbols list looks like:

[image: Nomenclature f a given function fi another function t a time variable ξ a space variable ξi a discretized space variable]

If you want to sub-divide this with titles, then it's better to use the `category` field rather than the `group` field (since `sort-field=category` ensures unbroken category blocks). This can be done by replacing:

```
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbol]
```

with:

```
\printunsrtglossary*[type=symbol,style=indexgroup]
{%
  \renewcommand{\glsxtrgroupfield}{category}%
}
```

which now produces:

[image: Nomenclature operator f a given function fi another function variable t a time variable ξ a space variable ξi a discretized space variable]

You can still use `\glsxtrsetgrouptitle` to set the group titles:

```
\printunsrtglossary*[type=symbol,style=indexgroup]
{%
  \glsxtrsetgrouptitle{operator}{Operators}%
  \glsxtrsetgrouptitle{variable}{Variables}%
  \renewcommand{\glsxtrgroupfield}{category}%
}
```

which produces:

[image: Nomenclature Operators f a given function fi another function Variables t a time variable ξ a space variable ξi a discretized space variable]

Comment: I like very much your solutions + explanations and your work in general. I just found more handy to use the command match={type=notation} rather that match={entrytype=entry} or not-match={entrytype=symbol}. I hope it has not counterpart or unexpected affects.